# Storybook & Next.js: Cannot find my component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, storybook

I am trying to create a template component in Storybook using Next.js with Typescript.

This is my component (ComponentTemplate.tsx):

```
import '../../styles/globals.css';

type ComponentTemplateProps = {
  text: string;
};

const ComponentTemplate: React.FC<ComponentTemplateProps> = ({ text }) => {
  return (
    <div className="text-red-700">
      <h1>{text}</h1>
      <p>This is a sample component.</p>
    </div>
  );
}; export default ComponentTemplate;
```

This is the ComponentTemplate.stories.tsx

```
// Import Component used in this story
import ComponentTemplate from './ComponentTemplate';

// Give Story a name and define component that belongs to this specific story
export default {
  title: 'templates/ComponentTemplate',
  component: ComponentTemplate,
  argTypes: {},
};

//
const Template = (args: any) => <ComponentTemplate {...args} />;

// Export function that returns our component. The name will define the name that is displayed in story book.
export const BaseTemplate = () => Template.bind({});
BaseTemplate.args = {
  text: 'I am not visible',
};
```

Unfortunately, I cannot see the text that should be displayed in Storybook. Help needed.